# Checking my results for Bayesian updating

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me whether I've completed the following questions regarding Bayesian updating correctly. I've been struggling with this topic for a while but I think I'm getting the hang of it. There aren't any answers available to me for these questions though so I'm not totally sure if I'm correct:

**Question 1**
[image]

My answer:

```
Three possible cases (001, 010, 100). Two outcomes per query (0, 1).

After final query;
x     || 001 | 010 | 100
P(x)  || 4/21|16/21| 1/21
```

**Question 2**
[image]

My answer:

```
Four cases (a, b, 4, 8). Four outcomes (a, b, 4, 8).

After final query;
x     ||  a  |  b  |  4  |  8
P(x)  || 1/6 | 1/6 | 1/3 | 1/3
```

**Question 3**

[image]

My answer:

```
Two cases (W1, W2). Three outcomes (1, 2, 3)

After final query;
x     ||  W1 |  W2
P(x)  || 3/15| 12/15
```

**...**

So, do those answers seem correct? I appreciate this is a lot of work to ask for but it would really help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a YouTube video which works through question 1. My answer is correct. I hope that means I got the other two right as well, but I would still like confirmation.

The video in question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKpmHnbqGTs